# iterating over a string in SQL to find all occurrences of a value & sum them up, based on a certain condition

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a bit of an SQL/Hive challenge.

In the DB, we receive the output of our XML like below. Which includes the name & value of XML records.

The value I am querying will look like:

```
rollover\5000,another\10000, rollover\1000, BillingTimeStamp\2017-06-15T01:00:05,timereset\2017-05-26T14:32:51
```

Which is derived from an XML tree that would look a bit like:

```
<property>
   <name>rollover</name>
   <value>5000</name>
</property>
<property>
   <name>another</name>
   <value>5000</name>
</property>
<property>
   <name>rollover</name>
   <value>7000</name>
</property>
```

...

So, I need to query and say:
IF this string includes the word rollover, sum the value. The problem is, the term rollover can appear multiple times, with multiple values.

The 'rows' are delimited by , and the columns by \

So the output if I were to split at a comma would be:

```
rollover\5000
another\5000
rollover\7000
...
```

Can anyone advise where I might even start? I've tried a few string functions and taking the value between the \ and the comma, but I don't know how to iterate over the string to find all occurrences.

Any help would be amazing!

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN "rollover" in "rollover\5000,another\5000, rollover\7000, BillingTimeStamp\2017-06-15,timereset\2017-05-26" 
            THEN
```

Comment: surely you query the XML as XML, not treating it as a string..

Comment: Unfortunately, it's already in the database, as a string, without the XML tags - I just have to work with it as it is :(